# how to read the file content and store file in a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to `read` a `css` file from `url` and try to save this file on my project directory.Can we do that using `nodejs`.

here is my code
https://repl.it/@naveennsit/ImpeccableQuarrelsomeDebugging

I am reading like this

```
const fs = require('fs');


    fs.readFileSync('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
```

I want to save this file in my `css` directory .Is it possible ?

currently I am getting this error

```
ror: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at /home/runner/ImpeccableQuarrelsomeDebugging/index.js:4:4
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
    at Ob
```

Comment: To get a network resource via http, you don't use the fs module.  Use one of [these libraries](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) for fetching data via http.  My personal favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

Comment: can you share any `sandbox` link with `got()`

Comment: What does "share a sandbox link" mean?  I don't know what that is.  You can make any http request with `got()` so anything that can be accomplished by sending or retrieving data over http can be done with `got()`.  The documentation contains a number of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the FS module can only read local files, try sending a GET request to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
then writing the response body to your css directory

heres an example:

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js')
  .then(function (response) {
   fs.writeFile('css.txt', response, () => {
   console.log('The file has been saved!');
  })
})
```

Comment: Exactly, readFileAsync will read a file from a directory on a local development machine (during development), or from a directory on the server on production.